# Email not send with attatchment in ci

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

When I use CI to send <kbd>email</kbd> with attachment there is no error but send with no attachment and contents.If it send without attachment email send with contents.

```
$this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->to('$tomail');
    $this->email->cc('$cmail');
    $this->email->from('noreply@******8');
    $this->email->subject('Gift Voucher');
    $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
    $data['content'] = 'Please find the attachment.<br> Reach us on : <a href="****">*****</a>';
    $data['footer'] = '&copy; ' . date("Y") . '********/  All rights reserved';
    $msg = $this->load->view('includes/mail_template', $data, TRUE);
    $path = base_url('assets/uploads/giftpurchase/giftvoucher_'.$payid);
    $this->email->attach($path);
    $this->email->message($msg);
    $this->email->send();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`base_url()` is provide you `HTTP` path, you should use there `Directory` path for mail attachment

Change

```
$path = base_url('assets/uploads/giftpurchase/giftvoucher_'.$payid);
// http://www.sitename.com/assets/uploads/giftpurchase/giftvoucher_.....
```

to

```
$path = {HERE_ROOT_PATH} 'assets/uploads/giftpurchase/giftvoucher_'.$payid;
// /var/www/html/assets/uploads/giftpurchase/giftvoucher_.....
```

**PS** : [**`getcwd()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) function is provide current working directory, you can use to get working `dir` path

```
$path = getcwd(). 'assets/uploads/giftpurchase/giftvoucher_'.$payid;
```

Comment: I've added comment beneath code lines, please check updated answer

Answer (score 2):

If You want to attach file from Your server You need to use path to file from Your filesystem, not from Your web-root

There're 2 useful constants in CodeIgniter:

`FCPATH` -> path to front controller (`index.php` at top level (above `/system/`))

`APPPATH` -> path to `/application/` folder

```
$path = FCPATH.'assets/uploads/giftpurchase/giftvoucher_'.$payid;
```